# HttpUrlConnection getResponseCode throwing java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, httpserver

here's what I'm running into.

```
    /**
 * Perform a post while retrieving an object in return.
 * @param urlPath path to requested resource
 * @param obj object to post
 * @return object retrieved from server
 */
private Object doPostGet(String urlPath, Object obj) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://" + this.host + ":" + this.port + urlPath);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/xml");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/plain");

        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.setDoOutput(true);

        con.connect();

        xStream.toXML(obj, con.getOutputStream());
        con.getOutputStream().close();

        Object outObj = null;
        if (con.getResponseCode() == Handler.OK) {

            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());

            assert in != null;

            outObj = xStream.fromXML(in);
            in.close();

        } else if (con.getResponseCode() == Handler.FAILED_AUTH) {
            //
        } else if (con.getResponseCode() == Handler.BAD_REQUEST) {
            //
        }
        con.disconnect();
        return outObj;
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}


java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:718)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:579)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:715)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:579)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1322)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
at mock.communicator.Communicator.doPostGet(Communicator.java:131)
at mock.communicator.Communicator.main(Communicator.java:102)
```

Line 131 of Communicator is "if (con.getResponseCode() == Handler.OK) {".  I'm not really sure whats causing it, and I'm sort of new to this stuff so my understanding is limited.  If you could help me understand what I'm doing wrong that would be great.  If you need any server side code let me know, I'm running my own HttpServer using HttpHandlers.

Comment: This is a server side issue. How is it responding?

Comment: You're right, the server is breaking but it's not throwing any exceptions which is wierd.  I think it might have something to do with the double POST thats occuring.  Whenever I do a POST it's sending it 2 times for some reason instead of just once.  Can you see any evidence of what would be causing that?

Comment: Not really. Debug line by line and check.

Comment: Sotirios Delimanolis was correct.  The server wasn't sending the response header.  In my HttpHandler, I just needed to add this bit of code.

    exchange.sendResponseHeaders(OK, 0);

And that solved the issue.

Thanks so much guys!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sotirios Delimanolis was correct. The server wasn't sending the response header. In my HttpHandler, I just needed to add this bit of code. 
    exchange.sendResponseHeaders(OK, 0);

And that solved the issue. Thanks so much guys!